# Connect a M.2 (B & M) key SSD into a B socket

Tags: ssd, sockets, m.2

I have bought a SSD with M.2 socket (B & M) key, but my computer just have a B key socket. My question is if I can connect the SSD in this B socket, and would it work correctly?

[image: SSD sockets]

Comment: Are the B and M key on the picture not reversed?
What is here named B key ( on the right) supports 4 pcie lanes

Comment: The picture is from wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should... a B&M module should work with either a B or M socket, this is by design.

> The B interface provides x2 PCIe, SATA, USB 2.0 and 3.0, audio, UIM,
>   HSIC, SSIC, I2C, and SMBus support. The M interface provides x4 PCIe,
>   SATA, and SMBus.

- [Source](http://electronicdesign.com/blog/what-s-difference-between-m2-modules)

If your module is B&M SATA (most likely), connecting it to a B or M socket should work fine since both types support SATA.

Of course, being a bootable device is another story, this depends on your hardware and UEFI.

Answer (score -6):

No, you cannot. If the socket only have 1 keyed, then you have to only insert 1 keyed NOT B+M keyed m.2. i already tried, its not working.

Comment: Their SSD can be installed in a M.2 slot with a B or M slot.  Their SSD absolutely is supported.