# Is M.2 NVMe SSD supported by Lenovo Thinkpad L490

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, storage, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L490 (2019) running i5 - 8th gen. It only has a B key slot (notch on the left with 5 pins to the left). I am looking to buy an SSD preferably M.2 NVMe but not sure if it’s supported. Couldn't find the compatibility information on the official website.

This is the one I am planning to buy:
[image]

Here is the image of the slot on the laptop. According to my research, slots like this support SATA SSD but it would be great if someone might confirm as I would like to get an NVMe as it is faster.

[image]

have already explored a lot of articles and videos about B key, M key, B+M key, NVMe and SATA M.2 SSDs, checked Crucial's website (which might be suggesting incorrect SSDs as they are not physically compatible) read the laptop's manual, etc. before posting the query here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The SSDs mentioned are of size 2280 but the maximum size that my laptop can accommodate is 2242. Apart from this, I am confused about the notch placement which is on the right on the SSDs suggested whereas it's on the left on my laptop's M.2 slot.

Comment: Not sure how a 2280 will fit in 2242 slot as the length is simply bigger. Also, are you sure flipping the SSD will work as doing that simply means we are plugging M key into B slot which I don't think will work. Thoughts?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I have explored a lot of resources present on the internet before posting it here.  Already emailed a local seller and brands like Crucial and EVM. Yet to hear back from them.

With all due respect, I think you should delete the comment suggesting to "just flip the SSD" if you are not sure about it as it might mislead people. Thanks for taking time and helping anyways.

Comment: Confusion 1: B key is on the left, M key is on the right. My laptop slot image shows B key and the SSD has M key. A lot of videos on YT also suggests that if the slots are on the left, it means only SATA is supported and NVMe is not supported. Are they compatible?
Confusion 2: It is nowhere written that the slot might be upside down (and it is not very obvious due to the whole B and M left right scenario), at least for me.
Confusion 3: Crucial website made it more confusing as they are suggesting incorrect sizes. It made me doubt if the type suggested on the website is correct or not.

Comment: https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_L490/ThinkPad_L490_Spec.PDF

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be compatible.

The Crucial site has
[SSD upgrades](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/thinkpad-l490#ssd)
that include PCIe Gen4 NVMe M.2 SSDs that go up to 4 TB in capacity.

There are other manufacturers that have similar offers, but Crucial
is very dependable (and guaranteed).

I suggest to examine carefully the images of the offered SSDs,
to enure that they seem compatible with your model.

Comment: If we notice closely, the notch on the SSD images on the Crucial's website are on the right side (M key) whereas the notch is on the left (B key) on my laptop's port. Does that mean I have to insert the SSD upside down?

Comment: I can't say, and this is why I cautioned to examine closely the images. You could ask Crucial Support, as they do answer back.

Comment: @Gaurav On NVMe drives, B key is 6 pins and M key is 5 pins. The drive connectors you show in both pictures are 5 pins; meaning M key. Read [more about it here](https://superuser.com/q/1066540/167207). So my comment about flipping the drive is 100% correct.

Comment: @Gaurav: There is no problem with flipping the drive, if you do that carefully and do not force anything. No harm should come to the drive, at most it won't work or not be recognized by the computer. If you buy specially a drive, ensure that the vendor has a good return policy.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense as both connectors in the images have 5 pins. I think it's a good idea to go ahead and order an SSD with a return policy. Thank you both.

Comment: The SSD didn't work after flipping.

Comment: Your computer seems to have more than one sub-model. Have Crucial Support answered?